# Disable memset generation for initialization in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, intrinsics, memset

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.
I prefer dynamic linking.

Compiler is generating `memset()` for each initialization like this: `STRUCT_TYPE var = { 0 };` How can I avoid that? I tried placing `#pragma intrinsic(memset)` after `#include <stdio.h>` but this does not help.

How can I force inline version of `memset()` and other functions like it?

Comment: Why is generating `memset` in the code bad for you, and what are you expecting that it do instead?

Comment: Inline version with `stosb`.

Comment: Assuming the variable is a global variable, what other function do you want the compiler and runtime support code to call to clear your structure? When you create a global variable (or local `static`) variable that you either don't initialize or initialize to all zeros, those are place in a special *segment* of the executable file that contains all those global or local static variables and their data. And as per the C++ specification those variables and their data has to be initialized to zero.

Comment: I do not need any function. I need small inline code with assembly instruction `stosb` to clear my structure.

Comment: Are you compiling with optimizations enabled?

Comment: You can trust that the `memset` function your compiler is using, especially for release builds, will be very optimized, and most likely faster than a simple `stosb` loop.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I know it. But now I do not need it. This is my question of how to avoid `memset` generation.

Comment: It appears to be size-dependent. For smaller structs there is no `memset` call.

Comment: @MichaelBurr yes. But without LTCG.
@AnT yes. But how to avoid it? I thought `#pragma instrinsic` is for inline replacement.

Comment: I think you need to tell us why this is a problem for you? Even a small loop for a couple of hundred bytes will take more time to clear one byte at a time compared to maybe 4 or 8 bytes that the `memset` function might use. Don't you trust the compiler to create the most optimal code? Or don't you trust the compiler in other regards? Then I really wonder why you are programming in C++ to begin with, instead of assembler directly.

Comment: is the issue that `memset` isn't being inlined as you want it to?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg this part of code must be base-independent and no intermodular calls are allowed. It is a kind of hotpach adding some functionality. Of course I can use assembler directly, but I need to know, how can I get `#pragma intrinsic` to work.

P. S. Added /Ob2 (any suitable inline expansion), still generates memset.

Comment: Can you post a small example (along with the command line used to compile it)?  Does adding `/Oi` help? Note that the docs for `#pragma intrinsic` says: "The compiler may call the function and not replace the function call with inline instructions, if it will result in better performance", so you might not be able to get the level of control that you want.  You could also try to link in your own `memset()` to avoid the intermodular calls.

Comment: @MichaelBurr sorry I could not, source files are large, and if I remove everything except variable definition just to prove that behaviour, compiler will optimize this program as it will do nothing. `/Oi` was added of course and it did not help. And I could not link with my own memset because of `error C2733: second C linkage of overloaded function 'memset' not allowed`,

Comment: @MichaelBurr try this: http://pastebin.com/dr9FNRQN